# Can I call a simple function a small number of times using multi-threading? c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I would like to call a function a small number of times (i.e, 4 times) using multithreading. Using the example from the **Solarian Programmer blog** (https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/), I have written this simple c++11 program:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <thread>
     #include <ctime>
     #include <math.h>

     #define PI 3.14159265358979323846

     static const int num_threads = 4;

     void call_from_thread(int tid) {
         std::cout << log(2) - 0.5*log(2*PI) - log(1.05) - pow(2.3-0.5,2)/(2*pow(1.05,2))<<std::endl;
     }

     int main() {
     std::thread t[num_threads];

     std::clock_t start;
    start = std::clock();

     //Launch a group of threads
     for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
         t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
     }

     std::cout << "Launched from the main\n";

     for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
         t[i].join();
     }
     std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

Of course, this example is trivial, and I do not need multi-threading here as the function returns always the same result. But, I plan to slightly modify this function so that there are some differences across threads. When running this code, I got something like :

```
Time: 0.806 ms
```

Now, if I modify the above code to allow just a single threaded code, I have the following:

```
     int main() {
     std::thread t[num_threads];

     std::clock_t start;
    start = std::clock();

     //Launch a group of threads
     for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
         call_from_thread(i);
     }

     std::cout << "Launched from the main\n";

     std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

Here, the running time is much lower:

```
Time: 0.116 ms
```

So, my question is can I call this simple function a small number of times using multi-threading in order to speed up my code? Basically, I would like to go below those 0.116 ms.

Note also, I am a newbie in c++ and parallelism, so sorry if my question does not seem relevant.

Comment: 0.116 ms is pretty much instantaneous, and multithreading costs CPU time in itself -- you need a much beefier `call_from_thread` function before the gains outweight the costs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could (in theory) do that, but be aware that creating a new thread is a complex and heavy operation (for the operating system and the standard C++ library). On Linux, [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) would use [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) which uses [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) (a low level [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)).

In practice (as a very naive rule of thumb), creating a thread might take a few milliseconds and is worthwhile only if that thread runs for more than a few milliseconds. So you might want to have [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)s. Remember than an elementary operation (a machine code instruction, e.g. doing a 32 bits addition) usually takes only a few *nanoseconds* (a million of them make a millisecond). So in real life using threads is worthwhile only for quite "complex" functions.

In other words, **[threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) are quite heavy resources** (e.g. because they usually have their own [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), typically of a megabyte, and they want to run on some other [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) of your processor).

Comment: I understand. Would you suggest me also to look at AVX vectorization instead of multithreading?

Comment: `I understand. Would you suggest me also to look at AVX vectorization instead of multithreading? ` - in your example compiler with optimizations turned on will reduce math calculations to minimum, additionally stream handling is more expensive than your calculations. Lastly - let compiler do AVX handling before you jump to intrinsics.

Answer (score 1):

I had followed the link that you provided and read this on their web page:

> Now, in order to see a parallel code at work we will need to give him a significative amount of work, otherwise the overhead of creating and destroying threads will nullify our effort to parallelize this code. The input image should be large enough to actually see an improvement in performance when the code is run in parallel. For this purpose I’ve used an image of 16000x10626 pixels which occupy about 512 MB in PPM format:

This page even states the same exact thing that user: [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) had already given. I agree with this assertion when using multiple threads.

Comment: @RangerBob No problem at all; thought it might help to clarify things! A simple analogy: Do you need to have 10 waitress or waiters to serve 4 tables? It's overkill for simplicity. However if you have 100 tables, will 1 waitress or waiter be sufficient without a bottleneck!